# 230V switch controlled by Arduino Uno (Atmega 328)

Tags: arduino, power-supply, switches, power-electronics, component-selection

I need to realize a switch for an electric motor whose power supply is at 230V.

That switch must be controlled by Arduino with a certain square wave signal. If the voltage was lower, I'd build a simple circuit with transistors used as switch. But I think it may be an hazard with 230V.

Which component can I use? I heard about solid state relay, but I do not know how to choose them and if they are right for this aim.

Comment: What have you found when you searched for similar projects (search for "Arduino mains switch")? What is the common way to do this, what do other (more experienced EEs) do?

Comment: if you're capable of 'building a simple circuit with transistors used as a switch', then you're capable of using google to look for SSRs (solid state relays) with a current and voltage rating exceeding the demands of your load.

Comment: How much current is going to pass through this "switch"?

Comment: What do you mean by "certain square wave signal". If you are switching the motor on and off, an SSR will do. If you're trying to get speed control via PWM, that won't work at all with most 230V electric motors (induction motors) so you need to be clear that you're trying to control a Universal (brushed) motor. Then you're looking at a triac (dimmer control) not an SSR.

Comment: @BrianDrummond not speed control, only on/off switch

Comment: @ElectronSurf about 0.7A (motor of 150W)

Comment: Here's a link with several guides: https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+relay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a contactor.  Like in the link.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Noark-40-Amp-2-Pole-Definite-Purpose-Contactor-Ex9CK40A20B7/300812949

These have a 24 volt AC coil and can switch on some big circuits.  I used something like this in one of my own projects.  If you can figure out how to switch a 24 volt AC circuit then you can turn on this contactor.  I'm not sure of the current draw on the coil but it's light enough for common low voltage household thermostats to handle.

In case the link is broken I'll point out that contactors like the one I linked to are apparently used for HVAC control, sprinklers, and heavy duty lighting.  I've seen them rated to 250 volts @ 50 amps.  Most any place that supplies home builders and HVAC will have them.  I suspect the do-it-yourself type of hardware store might not have them, and might not even know what they are if you ask.